# @see for methods in PHPStorm

Tags: phpstorm, phpdoc

I'm using PHPStorm 9 and would like to add in class member variables PHPDoc @see pointing to a method. Do I always have to prefix it with full class name including namespace or is there an easier way?

edit>

```
<?php
namespace Some\Very\Long\Namespace;
class MyClass
{
    /**
     * @see \Some\Very\Long\Namespace\MyClass::works()
     */
    protected $my_var;
    /**
     * @see doesnt_work()
     */
    protected $my_other_var;
    /**
     * Yeah it works
     */
    public function works() {}
    /**
     * fail ;(
     */
    public function doesnt_work() {}
}
```

Comment: Works just fine in 9.0.2. http://i.stack.imgur.com/hb4fg.png -- notice slightly altered namespace (that has no reserved "Namespace" in it). Quite possibly problem is in particular project on your side.

Comment: Yes you are right. I wrote it just as an example in SC editor without checking it really. Hmm I tested it and it actually does work. Maybe by accident I started v8 of PHPStorm instead of new one. Well thanks.

Comment: This does not seem to work in PHPStorm 2018.2.5